# javascript variable usage help

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Ok guys here's my dilemma, I just need some basic help... soo

if I have a set of variable say...

```
$h1 = ""
$h2 = ""
$h3 = ""
$h4 = ""
```

and i'm using a data attribute on the element, how can I use the number I pull to put into a string that acts as the variable name. so in the function below, you click a class item, it get's the value from the data attribute then I need to populate the #work_hold div with the corresponding variable. If I do what I have below, the $tme acts as a string and doesnt work. any ideas?

```
$(".box").click(function(){
var atr = $(this).attr("data-bsel"); 
$tme = '$h'+atr;
$('#work_hold').html($tme);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an array:

```
var h = [];
h[0] = ...;
h[1] = ...;
h[2] = ...;
...

$tme = h[atr];
```

You do NOT want to build variables dynamically. That just leads to utterly icomprehensible and impossible to debug code.

Comment: I like this answer best. Tackle how to use arrays before learning objects.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript [**objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```
var nameSpace = {"$h1": 109};

$(".box").click(function(){
    var atr = $(this).attr("data-bsel"); 
    $tme = nameSpace['$h'+atr];
    $('#work_hold').html($tme);

});
```

Comment: the first one work but I'm definitely going to read about these objects cause they'll prob help me in the future. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object here is a good example of objects in javascript